# Eclipse remove "export" history

Tags: java, eclipse

So, when I want to export a project to a jar file, I still see main classes and project which have already been removed (yes, properly deleted).
How do I get rid of those which don't exist anymore?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project `Project>clean`?

Comment: Didn't remove the history, but what it did do was remove the "can't find main method" bug in one of my projects; so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its stored here:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui\dialog_settings.xml
```

Comment: I found it in this file: <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml

Comment: May seem obvious, but be sure to close Eclipse first or it'll likely rewrite the history on exit back to what it was.

Comment: Same here:  <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml

Answer (score -1):

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\
```

Remove files from here.

Source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgpgE4zICQM

Comment: Not the same! This is where LAUNCH configurations are saved...