# Saving different Java JAR export destinations for different projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Is it possible to have Eclipse save different export paths for each of my projects?

I'm working on several .jar files at the same time, and when I export different projects I need them to end up in different places.

For example, in this case:

- Project A needs to be exported to /path/hello/A.jar
- Project B needs to be exported to /otherpath/goodbye/B.jar

Is it possible for Eclipse to remember my path for each project separately, and switch between them automatically?

Right now, I have to either reselect the correct destination when exporting a different project, or output the jar to the wrong paste and copy it over. It doesn't take long but it'd be so much nicer for it to be automatic.

I'm open to using plugins or something if doing so will resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Drop Down Box is available in Eclipse Export Wizard, you can change your export path from there. There is no option for remembering multiple export path.

[image: Eclipse Export Path]

Comment: Oops, late response but thank you for this! I did end up using this (never noticed it before you pointed it out), and it saves a lot of time! Accepted answer!

Comment: @Ronbo Fan My suggestion to you is *whenever you use any tool then you should go through available options in it. May be you find something interesting in existing app. Like export options as I answered.* It saves your lot of time.

Comment: Where are these configs saved? EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025197/eclipse-remove-export-history